# if statement depending on timer

Tags: ios, if-statement, timer, swift4

My code below is trying to stop the timer when it reaches 2 seconds. Thats what I have now is not working and I don't know what else to do. I thought viewdidappear would work. I think counter is the what I should make the if statement around.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var playbutton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var titlelabel: UILabel!

var timer = Timer()
var counter = 0.0
var isRunning = false


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titlelabel.text = "\(counter)"
    playbutton.isEnabled = true

}
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if counter == 1.9 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

@IBAction func btnreset(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer.invalidate()
    titlelabel.text = "\(counter)"
    counter = 0
    playbutton.isEnabled = true

    isRunning = false
}
@IBAction func btnplay(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !isRunning{
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        playbutton.isEnabled = false
    isRunning = true
    }

}
@objc func UpdateTime(){
    counter += 0.1
    titlelabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", counter)

}}
```

Comment: When you have to stop time you must invalidate() it and set nil....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

- Declare the timer as optional, then you can remove the `isRunning` variable, the timer is running if it's not `nil`

  ```
  var timer : Timer?

  ...

  @IBAction func btnplay(_ sender: UIButton) {
      if timer == nil {
          timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
          playbutton.isEnabled = false
      }
  }
  ```
- The check if the timer exceeds 2 seconds must be performed in the `updateTime` function, because it's called frequently. `viewDidAppear` is only called once.
- A check `== 1.9` does not work reliably because a floating point value is not exactly `1.9`.
  Check for *is equal or greater than*

  ```
  @objc func updateTime()
  {
      counter += 0.1
      titlelabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", counter)
      if counter >= 1.9 {
          timer?.invalidate()
          timer = nil
      }
  }
  ```
- In `btnreset` check if the timer is running and reset it to `nil`

  ```
  @IBAction func btnreset(_ sender: UIButton) {
      if timer != nil {
          timer!.invalidate()
          timer = nil
          titlelabel.text = "\(counter)"
          counter = 0
          playbutton.isEnabled = true
      }
  }
  ```